# Solve the equation $\log(z^2-1)=i\pi/2$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

I set $z=x+yi$, so:
$$ \log[(x+yi)^2-1]=\log(x^2+2xyi-y^2-1)=\log (r+iθ)=i\pi/2$$
than I get $x^2-y^2=1$
and I have no idea how to continue.

Answer (score 2):

It may be easier to note that:
$$z^2-1=e^{i\pi/2}= i$$
So that:
$$z=\pm \sqrt{i+1}$$

Comment: Or with some step in between, $z^2=1+i=\sqrt2\,e^{i\frac\pi4}$.

Comment: wow it seems much easier now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\log(z)=\ln|z|+i \arg(z)$. Then you have $$\log(z^2 -1)=\ln|z^2-1|+i \arg(z^2-1)=\frac{i\pi}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a few things and give maybe a slightly-different perspective. First, you need to define the branch cut you're using. I assume you're using Logz , where you're removing the segment $( -\infty,0]$ . Then notice that you're $w:= z^2 -1$ is purely imaginary, meaning that for Logw:=Ln|w|+iArgw, you have $Ln|w|=0$ (for $Lnx$ the natural log of $x$), and argument $\pi/2$ . Now, solve $Lnx=0$ for $x$ , and then find a point that is at an angle $\pi/2 $ from your base 0 angle. Note that if you use a different branch cut, then the solution will be different argument-wise.